# Running a for loop with time interval in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I'm trying to make a simple C# program that rolls two dice 100 times. For each roll, the dice images and some labels should change in the MainWindow. In order for each roll to be seen, I need some sort of time control. When my loop runs (triggered by a click event), the window just freezes for a while then shows the 100th roll. So it appears that the loop is running in the background (no exceptions are thrown), but the images are not updating in the window.

Using Thread.Sleep(500) is the closest I've gotten to this working. I've seen some timer solutions, but none that allowed a for loop. Whenever I try using a timer, I get threading issues.

the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    rollNumber++;
    labelRollNumber.Content = rollNumber;

    //creates two random integers to use for Image parameters
    int rdmInt1 = rdm.Next(0, 6);
    int rdmInt2 = rdm.Next(0, 6);

    //Changes dice images
    Image(rdmInt1, rdmInt2);

    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: Most window systems, including Windows (and by extension .NET's Windows Forms and WPF platforms) are event based, with a single thread servicing the UI. This means that, fundamentally, you can't have a simple loop that runs on the UI thread without it also preventing the UI thread from processing the normal window update/paint events (there's ugly workarounds such as manually pumping event messages on each iteration through the loop -- don't do this). The correct approach to this problem is to rewrite your loop body into a method that can be called back on the UI thread periodically by a timer

Comment: Use backgroundWorker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So it appears that the loop is running in the background

On the contrary, it runs directly on the UI thread and blocks your attemts to show images. And putting it to sleep does not help either because then your app simply does nothing, everything sleeps. It's just a coincidence that with 500 ms it works "better".

There's quite a few solution to this problem, I'll show you one of them.

First, I would encapsulate this logic to a class, but you don't have to.

```
class Dice
{
    // event fired when dice is rolled
    public event EventHandler<DiceEventArgs> OnRolled;

    public void Roll(int xTimes)
    {
        int rollNumber = 0;
        var rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < xTimes; i++)
        {
            rollNumber++;
            int rdmInt1 = rnd.Next(0, 6);
            int rdmInt2 = rnd.Next(0, 6);

            if (OnRolled != null)
                OnRolled(null, new DiceEventArgs(rollNumber, rdmInt1, rdmInt2));

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Now those special event args that provides all the info about current dice roll

```
class DiceEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int rollNumber;
    private int dice1;
    private int dice2;

    public int RollNumber { get { return rollNumber; } }
    public int Dice1 { get { return dice1; } }
    public int Dice2 { get { return dice2; } }

    public DiceEventArgs(int rollNumber, int dice1, int dice2)
    {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.dice1 = dice1;
        this.dice2 = dice2;
    }
}
```

and now the UI part

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dice = new Dice();
    dice.OnRolled += Dice_OnRolled;
    await Task.Run(() => dice.Roll(20));
}

void Dice_OnRolled(object sender, DiceEventArgs args)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => { button1.Text = args.RollNumber.ToString(); }));
}
```

this way you GUI will stay responsive all the time. I tested it with replacing the `Text` property of the button that starts rolling, but you can very well invoke your image change. Note, taht you have to invoke it using `Invoke` because events can be fired from a different thread.